# How to integrate QuickBooks Api in iOS App

Tags: ios7

I have been working since so many days on the QuickBook Api for ios sdk. But not able to find out the relevant link to Integrate this into my Project.

I have Done the following things in my app :-
1) I create an Account om the Intuit site.

2)From there i got the App token and other necessary thing like OAuth Consumer Key and OAuth Consumer Secret.

3)Now i have to link this with my app by which i can upload a file into the QuickBooks.

4) For uploading in the QuickBook I am using the following URL https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/335453891/attachable

i didn't find any solution. is there any quick book Api for ios sdk?

Can anyOne help me out from this, as i am stuck in this and i just want to get rid from this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no SDK for iOS yet, still working on figuring out their API myself, any further luck?